# Parsing physical new lines present in a string in Javascript/Node for storage

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encoding, utf-8

I am submitting data to the server using UTF-8 and encoding all entries being sent to the server. The objects I am sending are parameters with accompanying JSON data that partly consists of special characters.

### For example, for the description field of the JSON data, the actual input into a textarea is:

!@#$%^&*()

""''

this is a new line

---

The UTF-8 encoded data being sent to the server looks like:

```
&line={"description":"!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%0A%22%22''%0A%0Athis%20is%20a%20new%20line"}
```

with the parameter being 'line'.

On the server side, I am trying to parse the line parameter, but it has been decoded back into a readable string, with the special characters and new lines looking exactly like they did in the input data, albeit as part of JSON. When I try to parse this string into JSON, which now looks like:

```
    {"description":"!@#$%^&*() 

      ""'' 

      this is a new line"}
```

I get the 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token' error, which is expected assuming that it is caused by the breaks in the string. How would I rectify this issue? I have tried re-encoding the string using encodeURIComponent, but that encodes literally every element of the string.

I will ultimately be saving this data as part of a document in a NoSQL solution; the parsing is being done as part of a validation procedure to ensure entry data is of proper JSON format.

Comment: It works for me: `console.log(decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('{"description":"!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%0A%22%22\'\'%0A%0Athis%20is%20a%20new%20line"}').description))`

Comment: No you see, by the time I am checking the data for validation, it is no longer in the format with the special characters. It's a string that has already been decoded, as shown above in the second code snippet.

Comment: How has it "already been decoded?" Are you using Express, `querystring.parse()` manually, or something similar that is reading/parsing the data?

Comment: Yes, something like that. It's actually Koa, but similar module that is doing the initial decoding.